# Writing a ה or ק half on a patch and half off

Tags: safrus

When you need to patch a Torah, the practice is to write a letter either entirely on the original *klaf* or entirely on the patch, but not partly on one and partly on the other. See eg. [Keset HaSofer 18:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Keset_HaSofer.18.6):

> ובלבד שיכתוב כל האות על הטלאי. אבל אם כתב מקצת אות על היריעה ומקצתו על הטלאי פסול. ולא עוד אלא אפי' אם כתב כל האות כולו על היריעה אלא שמקצת הדיו מצד האחד של האות עובר גם על הטלאי לא מהני הקפת הגויל שבטלאי להאות שנכתב על היריעה אלא צריך להיות מוקף גויל ביריעה עצמה בלא טלאי. והאות הנכתב על הטלאי צריך להיות מוקף גויל בטלאי עצמו בלא היריעה:
>
> As long as you write the entire letter on the patch. But if you write half of a letter on the *klaf* and half on the patch, it's *pasul*. And not only that, but if you write the entire letter on the *klaf* but some of the ink on one side of the letter goes onto the patch, the "surrounding by *klaf*" from the patch is insufficient for the letter that's written on the *klaf* [that is, it's not considered as surrounded by blank *klaf*, as is required of every letter — *trans.*], but rather it needs to be entirely surrounded by *klaf* on the [original] *klaf* itself without the patch. And the letter written on the patch needs to be surrounded by *klaf* on the patch itself, without the [original] *klaf*.

The problem seems to be one of *mukaf g'vil*, that each letter needs to be fully surrounded by blank *klaf*, and that the patch and the original *klaf* don't combine for this purpose. (There are other opinions, see [Taz YD 280:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.280.4).)

There are two letters, though, that consist of two parts, namely, the letters ה and ק. According to the opinion above that requires writing an entire letter either on the original *klaf* or entirely on the patch, is it permitted to write one piece of the ה/ק on the patch and the other piece on the original *klaf*?